# Inserting XML to XMLDocument

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

My XML is as follows:

```
 <School>
   <ClassA>
     <Students>
        <Student>
           <Name>AB</Name>
           <Score>90</Score>
        </Student>
     </Students>
   </ClassA>
 </School>
```

Loading the XML into `XmlDocument`

```
  XmlDocument xmlRequest = new XmlDocument();
  xmlRequest.LoadXml(myXML);
```

Now reading the array of records in LINQ and creating the XML dynamically

```
  var xmlSubjects = new XElement("subjects",
                    from c in arrySubjects
                    select new XElement("subject",
                         new XElement("English", c.English),  
                         new XElement("Social", c.Social)
                    ));
```

From above i am getting below XML:

```
     <Subjects>
        <Subject>
           <English>L Author</English>
           <Social>M Author</Social>
        </Subject>
     </Subjects>
```

I want to add this XML into my Parent XML. I tried by using below code

```
    XmlNode xElt = xmlRequest.SelectSingleNode("//ClassA");
    XmlElement xNewChild = xmlRequest.CreateElement(xmlSubjects.ToString());
    xmlRequest.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(xNewChild, xElt);
```

I need help to add my XML string as first element of ClassA.

Final XML:

```
 <School>
   <ClassA>
     <Subjects>
        <Subject>
           <English>L Author</English>
           <Social>M Author</Social>
        </Subject>
     </Subjects>
     <Students>
        <Student>
           <Name>AB</Name>
           <Score>90</Score>
        </Student>
     </Students>
   </ClassA>
 </School>
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
XmlDocumentFragment xmlfrag = xmlRequest.CreateDocumentFragment();
xmlfrag.InnerXml = xmlSubjects ;
xmlRequest.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(xmlfrag,xmlRequest.DocumentElement.FirstChild);
```

Comment: It works fine but i want to insert xmlSubjects under <School><ClassA>
before <Students>

Comment: Thank you it is working fine :)

I have one more scenario where myxml = <School><ClassB></ClassB><ClassA><Student></Student></ClassA>

Now i want to add <Subject></Subject> Under <ClassA> 

Please suggest me here

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're mixing `XmlDocument` and `XDocument` here.  I would parse the original XML using `XDocument`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(myXML);
```

And then you can find the element to insert at and add your new subjects:

```
var classA = doc.Descendants("ClassA").First();
classA.AddFirst(xmlSubjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend mixing the `XmlDocument` and `XDocument` APIs together because the resulting code will be difficult to understand and maintain, and also potentially have performance issues due to conversions between the two representations.  (Perhaps you're boxed in by legacy code constraints?)

That being said, you can stream your `XElement xmlSubjects` into the `XmlNode` representation of the `<ClassA>` element as follows:

```
        XmlNode xElt = xmlRequest.SelectSingleNode("//ClassA");

        using (var writer = xElt.CreateNavigator().PrependChild())
        using (var reader = xmlSubjects.CreateReader())
        {
            writer.WriteNode(reader, false);
        }
```